# C++ Аргумент типа "char *" не совместим с параметром "LPWSTR". VS 2015

Tags: c++

В коде выскакивает ошибка:

> "Аргумент типа "char *" не совместим с параметром "LPWSTR"." Visual
>   Studio 2015

Код:

```
string ExePath() {
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Беда в том, что программу вы собираете с поддержкой юникода, поэтому и вызовы WinAPI ожидают wchar_t* а не char*.

Варианты решения:

Неплохой:

- уйти с головой в юникод, использовать std::wstring и wchar_t
- наоборот, отключить для всего проекта юникод.

Костылявый:

- вызвать не-юникодную версию GetModuleFileNameA()

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить что ошибка при вызове GetModuleFileName. У вас есть три варианта: объявить buffer с типом TCHAR, вызывать GetModuleFileNameA явно или в настройках проекта отключить использование Unicode.

На будущее: вопроса в вопросе нет. Где именно ошибка не ясно. Так делать не надо.